# Google chrome doesn't render the fonts properly.

Tags: fonts, google-chrome

I have attached an image of the badly rendered font.

[image: bad rendered fonts image]

This started happening after upgrading 12.04 (I was on 10.10 before that). The chrome version is Version 22.0.1229.39 beta. Font for the text in multi-color is "CallunaBlack". If I change it to Arial or Times New Roman, it is displayed correctly. The problem may be limited to webfonts.

Initially I had problem with many fonts. Taking hint from some earlier answers, I created .fonts.conf as below. This helped in getting the regular fonts rendered correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
   <const>none</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintslight</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
    <const>lcdlegacy</const>
   </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

I tried different options for the parameters here but no success.

Everything looks good on firefox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same problem. Following steps fixed the issue.

1. Install `gnome-tweak-tool`: 
   `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
2. Open Advanced settings from dash.
3. Select "Fonts".[image]
4. Select "Grayscale" or "None" for the "**Antialiasing**" setting.

This issue is with the recent version of chrome. If you don't want to do the above steps I would recommend you to downgrade the chrome version.